# How to search and replace with matching hits in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a large text file with html tags, starting as `<input name="x1"` in each lines. I want to replace the tags to `x1 : <input name="x1"`. How can I do so?

I tried to search pattern as `<input name="\S+"` to match the words. It works fine. But, I don't know to replace with matching words to the same tag.

I tried `$1 : $0` as replace pattern, but no hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used pattern **`<input name="(\S+)"`** to find and pattern **`\1 : $0`** to replace.

The test link is available at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mqcyXs/2).

Comment: You'd better use `"([^"]+)"` instead of `"(\S+)"` because you will have errors if there are several `<input...` in a single line.